Fastlane, Github actions. Scheme is not currently configured for the build action
When I upload React Native app to testflight with Github actions and Fastlane I get build error
xcodebuild: error: Scheme qa is not currently configured for the build action.
Exit status: 66

All my schemes are shared in Xcode. When I started command locally, all works fine, upload succeeded.
My .yml file:
name: Release

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - qa

jobs:
  release-ios:
    name: Build and release iOS app
    runs-on: macos-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/setup-node@v1
        with:
          node-version: "18.x"
      - uses: ruby/setup-ruby@v1
        with:
          ruby-version: '3.2.0'
      - name: Remove Derived Data
        run: rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
      - name: Yarn Install
        run: yarn
      - name: Install Fastlane
        run: cd ios && bundle install && cd ..
      - name: Install pods
        run: cd ios && pod install && cd ..
      - name: Execute Fastlane command
        run: cd ios && fastlane qa

my FastFile:
default_platform(:ios)

DEVELOPER_APP_ID = ENV["DEVELOPER_APP_ID"]
DEVELOPER_APP_QA_IDENTIFIER = ENV["DEVELOPER_APP_QA_IDENTIFIER"]
DEVELOPER_APP_STAGE_IDENTIFIER = ENV["DEVELOPER_APP_STAGE_IDENTIFIER"]
PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER = ENV["PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER"]
TEMP_KEYCHAIN_USER = ENV["TEMP_KEYCHAIN_USER"]
TEMP_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD = ENV["TEMP_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD"]
APPLE_ISSUER_ID = ENV["APPLE_ISSUER_ID"]
APPLE_KEY_ID = ENV["APPLE_KEY_ID"]
APPLE_KEY_CONTENT = ENV["APPLE_KEY_CONTENT"]
GIT_AUTHORIZATION = ENV["GIT_AUTHORIZATION"]

def delete_temp_keychain(name)
  delete_keychain(
    name: name
  ) if File.exist? File.expand_path("~/Library/Keychains/#{name}-db")
end

def create_temp_keychain(name, password)
  create_keychain(
    name: name,
    password: password,
     default_keychain: true,
     unlock: true,
  )
end

def ensure_temp_keychain(name, password)
  delete_temp_keychain(name)
  create_temp_keychain(name, password)
end

desc 'GitHub actions release'
lane :version do |options|
  updateVersion(options)
  increment_build_number(xcodeproj: 'My.xcodeproj')
end

# QA
lane :qa do |_options|
  app_identifier = DEVELOPER_APP_QA_IDENTIFIER
  keychain_name = TEMP_KEYCHAIN_USER
  keychain_password = TEMP_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD
  ensure_temp_keychain(keychain_name, keychain_password)
  create_keychain(
      name: TEMP_KEYCHAIN_USER,
      password: TEMP_KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD,
      timeout: 1800,
      default_keychain: true,
      unlock: true,
      lock_when_sleeps: false
    )
  import_certificate(
    certificate_path: 'MyCertificate.cer',
    keychain_name: keychain_name,
    keychain_password: keychain_password
  )
  install_provisioning_profile(path: './profile.mobileprovision')
  update_project_provisioning(
    xcodeproj: 'My.xcodeproj',
    target_filter: 'github',
    profile: './profile.mobileprovision',
    build_configuration: 'Debug'
  )
  api_key = app_store_connect_api_key(
           key_id: APPLE_KEY_ID,
           issuer_id: APPLE_ISSUER_ID,
           key_filepath: "AuthKey.p8",
           in_house: false # optional but may be required if using match/sigh
    )
    recreate_schemes(project: "My.xcodeproj")
  build_app(
    project: "My.xcodeproj",
    scheme: 'qa',
    clean: true,
    export_method: "app-store",
    export_options: {
        provisioningProfiles: {
            "myBundleId" => "myProfile"
        },
    }
)

  upload_to_app_store(
    force: true,
    reject_if_possible: true,
    skip_metadata: true,
    skip_screenshots: true,
    languages: ['en-US'],
    release_notes: {
      'default' => "Shiny and new",
    },
    submit_for_review: true,
    precheck_include_in_app_purchases: false,
    automatic_release: true,
    submission_information: {
      add_id_info_uses_idfa: true,
      add_id_info_serves_ads: true,
      add_id_info_tracks_install: true,
      add_id_info_tracks_action: false,
      add_id_info_limits_tracking: true,
      export_compliance_encryption_updated: false
    },
    api_key: api_key
  )
end

Any suggestions?
I expected successfull build and uploading to testflight, but got error.

It sounds like the issue you're encountering is related to the configuration of your Xcode project schemes when running Fastlane through GitHub Actions. Here are steps to troubleshoot and potentially resolve this problem:
1. Verify Scheme Configuration
Ensure that the scheme you're trying to build (qa in this case) is properly configured for building in your Xcode project. Sometimes, schemes might not be correctly shared or configured for certain actions.

Open Xcode: Launch your Xcode project.
Navigate to Scheme Settings: Go to Product > Scheme > Edit Scheme....
Check Build Configuration: Ensure that the correct build target and configuration are set for the scheme you want to use (e.g., qa).

2. Share Schemes
Make sure that your schemes are shared correctly in your Xcode project. This step ensures that these schemes are available for use across different systems and environments.

Open Xcode: Launch your Xcode project.
Manage Schemes: Go to Product > Scheme > Manage Schemes....
Check Sharing Status: Ensure that the checkbox for sharing your scheme is selected (checked).

3. Update Fastlane Configuration
In your Fastfile or wherever you have defined your Fastlane configuration, ensure that you are specifying the correct scheme for building.
lane :build_and_upload do
  # Replace 'qa' with your actual scheme name
  build_app(scheme: "qa", ...)
end


this is just chatgpt
